# Use robots.txt to prevent crawlers from getting old versions of Trac pages

Tags: apache-2.2, trac, robots.txt

looking at my Apache access.log I see that crawlers tend to get old versions of pages and documents, like:

```
119.63.196.86 - - [10/Jun/2011:10:36:31 +0200] "GET /wiki/News?version=14 HTTP/1.1" 200 6073 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
```

I'd like them not to append the `?version=x` suffix to URLs, so that they only get the most recent contents.

Is there a way to do this via the `robots.txt` file (or other mechanisms that I don't know?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using trac out of the box then these pages have both NOINDEX and NOFOLLOW on them so much as they will get crawled they won't be indexed.